# Continue page numbering from a specific section in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, ms-office

How does one continue the page numbering from a *specific section* in MS Word?

Consider the following scenario:

> - MS Word document with 3 sections A, B, and C.
> - Page numbering starts at `1` on the first page of section A (ends at, let's say, `3`, on page 3).
> - No page numbering (or alternate page numbering) in section B.
> - In section C, page numbering continues from that of section A (first page-number of section C is `<last_page_A> + 1 = 4`).
>
> Now let the number pages in section A, B, and C vary and the page numbering
> to automatically adapt. The document has a Table of Contents.

Is this possible using the MS Word GUI through some trickery I am not aware of? If not, how could one do this with MS Office Field Codes or VBA?

To my knowledge, the MS Word GUI only lets you continue page numbering from the previous section, or alternatively, lets you manually handle the page numberings:

[image: The figure above shows the "Format Page Numbers" child window in MS Word (quickly accessible by right-clicking a PAGE Field).]

Comment: If Section A is Pages 1 to 3 you want section C to start with Page 4 irrespective of how many pages there are in Section B.  Is that correct.

Comment: Yes, @Freeflow, that is correct. I will edit the question to make that explicit.

Comment: Will you ever need the page numbers to appear in a TOC or other cross reference.

Comment: I am going to say _yes_, but feel free to share a cross reference-free-Word-doc solution if you have one.

Comment: Note: This question came up when I was writing a thesis, a thesis which is now already submitted. I don't _need_ anything, I am simply curious about all of this. It also feels like something people may have a use for in the future (including myself).

Comment: Its likely that you would need to implement a VBA solution.  The only non VBA solution I can come up with produces a mismatch between the number on the page and that in the toc or cross reference.  

The non VBA partial solution involves putting a bookmark on the last page of a section and then using a formula to add the page reference of the bookmark to the current page number which is restarted at 1.  You end up with a formula field 

{={pageref EnOfSectionBookmark} + {Page}}

Answer (score -1):

To insert a page number cross-reference, follow these steps:

1. Insert a bookmark on the page containing the information you want to cross-reference.
2. Position the insertion point where you want the cross-reference to occur.
3. Press Ctrl+F9 to insert field brackets. Make sure the insertion point stays between the brackets.
4. Type pageref followed by the bookmark name used in step 1.
5. Press F9 to update the field information.

Please refer to the following link:

[Inserting Page Number Cross-References](https://word.tips.net/T000957_Inserting_Page_Number_Cross-References.html)

[Controlling the Format of Cross-References](https://word.tips.net/T000141_Controlling_the_Format_of_Cross-References.html)

Comment: Bruce, this is not really an answer to my question. Please explain why you are giving these instructions on _page number cross-references_. I.e. how are those instructions relevant to my question? I think user @freeflow did a good job at doing that. If you want, maybe give him credit, and make your contribution into a proper answer. I think a VBA solution is what I am looking for, however. Nevertheless, for those with no need for a TOC, instructions on page number cross-references and Field Codes may be helpful.